# How to hide the extra cell from UITabbar More menu iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, hide, cells

I have UITabBarController with 6 tabs. Now, the last 2 screens(tabbar items) are added in More Tabitem. There, it is in UITableview cells, first two rows have two tabbar items(2 screens). Now, my problem is to hide the other cells(set separate color as white). How can i do this? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your all answers. I have solved the problem with Mr.Ravin's answer.

```
UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *) [[musicTabBar.moreNavigationController topViewController] view];
        moreTableView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.94 green:0.96 blue:0.96 alpha:1];
        [moreTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 

        for (UITableViewCell *cell in [moreTableView visibleCells]) 
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
```

This code helped me to show only two rows and hide all other rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  UITableView *moreTableView = 
(UITableView *) [tabBarController.moreNavigationController topViewController] view] ;
```

will give you reference to the table that is used in moreNavigationController.

```
[moreTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

will help you  in setting set separator color.

and after this you may need to set cell's background color .(as when this separator color is white it will certainly hide the separator in-between the cells with data ;) ).

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i change the tableview style. I have tried to set the style as grouped. moreTableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped; It shows an error that read-only property. How can i set the style. I want to show only the two items with background cell image and hide all other cells. Thanks. I hope you can solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you Ravin. I solved the problem. Once again i thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky, but perhaps, you can alter the rowHeight in the table and make it so that there are only 2 cells shown based on the height. If you do this, then you can subclass the UITableViewCell to perhaps add other things to the cell that give some information about the last two views. 
Other than that, you can alter the size of the tableView so that only 2 cells will be displayed.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Mr.Tams. Your lines helped me to found the answer quick. Thanks.